# Instantiate a private class in php

Tags: php, class, private, instantiation

I am trying to access the Dog class with private internal variables and I am trying to instantiate these variables at the bottom, though it does run it does not change "loud to "LOUD" for bark, can anyone explain why this happening?

__construct is purposely left blank

```
class Dog {
    private $_bark='loud'; //how loud the bark is
    private $_goodBoy='yes';//how well dog behaves
    private $_wetnessOfNose='moist';//how wet the dog nose is 

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function bark() {
        // retrieves how loud the bark is
        return $this->_bark;
    }

    public function goodboy() {
        // retrieves status of dog behavior
        return $this->_goodBoy;
    }

    public function nose() {
        // retrieves how wet dogs nose is
        return $this -> _wetnessOfNose;
    }
}

$myDog= new Dog();
$myDog->bark('LOUD');
echo "myDog's bark is " . $myDog->bark();
```

Comment: You should enable error reporting in your code. PHP will be complaining about passing an argument to `bark()` when it was not coded to accept one.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  If you modify `bark()` to accept an argument and set the value of `$this->_bark` to that arg before returning it, you'll achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: `__construct is purposely left blank` then it can be removed.

Comment: Also you might be looking for `__set()` not sure.

Comment: You invoke method bark() with argument but in the method definition there are no arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written getters, but not setters. To set a private property, you will need to write class methods that set that private property.

## Getters and setters

You could write two methods, `getBark` and `setBark` (likely the most self-documenting), the former of which would return `$_bark` and the latter would take a `$bark` parameter and set `$this->_bark` to `$bark`.

**Example:**

```
public function getBark() {
    return $_bark;
}

public function setBark($bark) {
    $this->_bark = $bark;
}
```

## Combined getter and setter

Alternatively, you could combine both the `get` and `set` methods and just use a `bark` method like you currently have. It should take a `$bark` parameter and check if it's not `null` using PHP's [`isset()` function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), then set `$_bark` to `$bark` and exit the method without returning anything. If the parameter `$bark` is **not** set, it just returns the value of the private property `$_bark`. So, essentially, it covers the duty of both methods.

This method can be called as `$myDog->bark()` to get the value of `$_bark`, **or** called as `$myDog->bark('LOUD');` to set the value of `$_bark` to `'LOUD'`.

**Example:**

```
public function bark($bark) {
    if (isset($bark)) { // If you've supplied a $bark parameter...
        $this->_bark = $bark; // Set $_bark to the value of the parameter
        return; // Exit the method without returning anything (does not continue outside of the if statement
    }

    return $this->_bark; // No parameter was supplied, so just return the value of $_bark
}
```

## Bad practice

Finally, you **could** make the `_bark` property public, but you **really** shouldn't do that.

Comment: `(isset($bark)` => `(isset($bark))` change it please.

Comment: I understand the first example, but not so much your second one, is there something i could look at to better understand whats going on?

Comment: @Kirtar I've slightly updated my answer with some more explanation. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing value of variable `$_bark`, you are returning one. You are providing parameter to function `bark` when there is nothing to provide.

```
class Dog {
    private $_bark='loud';       // how loud the bark is
    private $_goodBoy='yes';     // how well dog behaves
    private $_wetnessOfNose='moist';    // how wet the dog nose is

    public function setBark($newBark){
        //sets how loud the bark is
        $this->_bark = $newBark;
    }

    public function bark(){
        //retrieves how loud the bark is
        return $this->_bark;
    }

    public function goodboy(){
        //retrieves status of dog behavior
        return $this->_goodBoy;
    }

    public function nose(){
        //retrieves how wet dogs nose is
        return $this -> _wetnessOfNose;
    }
}

$myDog= new Dog();
$myDog->setBark('LOUD');
echo "myDog's bark is " . $myDog->bark();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `bark()` seems to be getter, not setter, so the call

```
$myDog->bark('LOUD');
```

makes completely no sense as it lacks use of return value + you try to pass argument even if nothing expects it.

It's good practice to name getters like `getBark()` and setters like `setBark()` to avoid issues like that and you should remove current `bark()` and introduce

```
public function getBark(){
    return $this->_bark;
}

public function setBark($bark){
    $this->_bark = $bark;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this format and it now works i now realized that i didn't have a setter.